# Windows says my folder containing music is 61.3TB even though my hard drive is only 500GB

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-transfer

I recently moved all of the music from my phone onto my pc, so I could do a factory reset of my phone. After resetting my phone, I am now trying to move the music back onto it, but whenever I try, it takes hours just to move one album.

While trying to figure out why this might be I went into properties, and it is showing 61.3TB for all of my music. The true size is only around 30GB. Does anyone know why windows is showing this file size and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The misreported folder size could be one of several reported [bugs](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/wrong-calculation-of-folder-size-by-windows/2da61a1b-d2fd-472a-ae12-a17a4cc8f7e2) in Windows 10, such as the file explorer confusing a file's metadata with its byte size.

One quick way to try correcting this is running the utility [TLPD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tlpd/), which finds files whose paths exceeds 255 characters, which can confuse the file explorer.

Or just use one of the many non-Microsoft programs that measures folder size and disk usage.

---

Slow and incorrect copying from Windows 10 to phones has also been [reported](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3221331/dont-use-windows-10-to-move-data-on-your-android-phone.html).  If you can, first copy the folder to a Windows 7 PC, and then from there to the phone.